# debug adapter server not starting from vscode

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to implement a debugger plugin for vscode that uses a separate DAP server process.  It seems like when I click "Start Debugging", nothing is happening.  For simplicity, I just created a one-line script that touches a file to see if the program is being run, and it is not.

Here's the "contributes" section of my `package.json` file:

```
    "debuggers": [
      {
        "type": "mylang",
        "label": "My language debug",

        "program": "./test.sh",
        "languages": [ "mylang" ]

      }
    ]
```

And `test.sh` is just:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "hello world" >> output.txt
```

Perhaps relatedly, I tried running the [mock debug adapter](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mock-debug) after changing `runMode` to `external` in `src/extension.ts`, and it doesn't work; perhaps there is a problem with vscode launching executables on my platform.

I'm using VSCode 1.84.2 on Ubuntu.

All of the examples I can find are building a full-blown extension which has typescript code that launches the process; I'd like to avoid that complexity if possible

Comment: See also: [question on vscode-mock-debug github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mock-debug/issues/110) and [my repo](https://github.com/mdgeorge4153/CVLDebugPrototype/tree/main)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing `launch.json` in my sample workspace